# Javascript event will not fire up after Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a form (input, textarea and submit button) and I also have a list of items. I wrote the following script to:

1. when I click a list item the textarea will show the list item text content
2. on submit, ajax call will POST the form without refreshing the page

the code works fine in the first time but then I will not be able to update the textarea when I click on a list item anymore (point #1 above will not work again).

```
var ul = document.getElementById('messages-list');

var listItems = Array.prototype.slice.call(ul.querySelectorAll("li"));

listItems.forEach(function (item) {
  item.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    document.getElementById("message").textContent = this.textContent;
  });
});

$(function () {

  $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'send_sms.php',
      data: $('form').serialize(),
      success: function () {
        alert('msg sent');
        $('textarea').val("");
        $('#phoneNumber1').val("");
      }
    });

  });

});
```

Can you please help me fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked your browser console for errors?

Comment: I get this after form submission: [Violation] 'DOMContentLoaded' handler took 164ms
jquery.min.js:4 [Violation] 'load' handler took 902ms

Comment: You should ideally put all your code inside the DOM ready handler, ie `$(function() { ... })`. That being said, if your code works the first time, that's probably not the problem

Comment: Also, assuming `#message` is a `<textarea>`, you set the text using the `value` property, **not** `textContent`

Comment: Why aren't you using jQuery to bind the click handler? `$("#message-list li").click(function () { $("#message").text($(this).text()); })`

Comment: The problem you're having sounds like what happens if you replace `#message-list` dynamically. But I don't see any code that does that in the question.

Comment: Do you create html by ajax/javascript ? If yes , use $(selector).live("click",function(){  })

Comment: @SalehMosleh Get up to date. `.live()` was deprecated in jQuery 1.6 and removed in 1.9.

Comment: @Barmar so use $(selector).on("click",function(){  })

Comment: @SalehMosleh No, it should be `$("static-selector").on("click", "dynamic-selector", function() {...})`

Comment: I found out that the problem does not exist in Microsoft Edge. only in Firefox and Chrome!!!! @Barmar Phil SalehMosleh

Comment: You need to provide an MCVE that demonstrates the problem. There's not enough code here to diagnose. Have you checked the Javascript console for errors?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Barmer for all your suggestions. Conan solution below fixed the problem. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot @SalehMosleh for all your suggestions. Conan solution below fixed the problem. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys...

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your forEach to use `.val()` when updating the `textarea`:

```
listItems.forEach(function (item) {
  item.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    $('#message').val(this.textContent);
  });
});
```

As stated by others, `.val()` is the preferred method of getting / setting content - mixing this with `textContent` appears to cause the issue you're experiencing.

Comment: I found out that the problem does not exist in Microsoft Edge. only in Firefox and Chrome!!!! @Conan

Comment: @Ray try $(this).text() instead of this.textContent. Look does it work ?

Comment: @Ray (last try) , try to put your codes inside $( window ).load(function() {     })

Comment: actually, this fixed the problem. Thanks a lot @Canon